# How to Bode plot an array of transfer functions?

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

I have some transfer functions corresponding to an LLC converter. Each one is different, I'm changing a single parameter to visualize the changes in the frequency response. I have something like this:

```
V(1)=Voutput;
V(2)=Voutput2;
V(3)=Voutput3;
```

Then I plot them using:

```
figure(1)
optsV = bodeoptions('cstprefs');
optsV.FreqUnits = 'kHz';
bode(V, optsV)
```

The problem is that every transfer function is being plotted in a different chart:

[image]

How can I plot them in a single chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like

```
bode(V(1),'r',V(2),'g',V(3),'b', optsV)
```

where `V1,V2,V3` are your various transfer functions.

They will be plotted as 3 lines with the three colors red, green, blue.

EDIT, in reply to the comment: if as you write in the comments they are very many, you can create the figure, call `hold on`, and plot all the transfer functions in a for loop, something like this:

```
first_tf = tf(1,[1,1]);
%your example of many TF.
V = [first_tf,2*first_tf,3*first_tf];
figure
hold on

for j=1:length(tfdata(V))
    bode(V(j))
end
```

With output like:[image]

Comment: But in the case I have like 20 o 30 of this transfer functions, how can I plot them without typing one by one? I'm generating them in a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following and put all of them in the same command:

```
bode(V(1),V(2),V(3), optsV)
```

If you want to use a loop to automatically plot all of the transfer functions you can use the following code:

```
for i = 1:size(V,2)
    bode(V(i), optsV)
    hold on
end
```

Here is a short demonstration:

```
V(1)=tf([1 0 0],[1 1]);
V(2)=tf([1 2 0],[1 1]);
V(3)=tf([1 1 0],[1 1]);

figure(1)
optsV = bodeoptions('cstprefs');
optsV.FreqUnits = 'kHz';

bode(V(1),V(2),V(3), optsV)
legend('V1','V2','V3')
```

[image: desc]